# PHP - JSON Parsing - add and remove object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am getting `[{"2016":"200"},{"2017":"200"}]`  This JSON string from server , I want to append another object ie. `{"2018":"324"}` at the end of the existing JSON array and want to delete object at the 0th index the existing JSON array so that the my desired result **`[{"2017":"200"}{"2018":"324"}]`** can be obtained.
Here's what i am doing

```
        $str = json_decode($x1,TRUE);                    //x1 is my JSON
        array_push($str, array("2018"=>"324"));     //adding another object
        unset($str[0]);                             //removing 0th index
        $s = json_encode($str,TRUE);                    //making JSON again
        echo $s;
```

***Problem here is `$s` giving output in object form like `{"1":{"2017":"200"},"2":{"2018":"35"}}` While what is wanted is `[{"2017":"200"}{"2018":"324"}]`***

Comment: Then you need to reindex your array again, with `array_values()` OR remove the value from the array with `array_splice()`.

Comment: `$s = json_encode((array)$str);` Why are u using `TRUE` on `json_encode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest better approach, using [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array-shift):

```
$json = json_decode($x1, TRUE);   // decoding

array_shift($json);               // removing first element

$json[] = [ "2018" => "324" ];    // adding last element

$str = json_encode($json);        // encoding

echo $str;
```

As others already pointed out, you getting object equivalent because your array not starting from `0` index, so it is converted in javascript object with numeric keys. I'm using `array_shift()` to remove first element. It will also reset indices in array. It also would be (insignificantly) faster, if you remove first key before adding other elements to array.